# Get subarray of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array ($skus), which looks like this;

```
$skus[0] = "hello";
$skus[1] = "world";
$skus[2] = "sky";
$skus[3] = "is";
$skus[4] = "blue";
```

My question is, how can I get a subset of this array based on another array, i.e. the subset array is;

```
$words = array(0,2,4);
```

which will return to me an array with `["hello", "sky", "blue"]`, i.e.

```
$return[0] = "hello";
$return[1] = "sky";
$return[2] = "blue";
```

Comment: did u tried the solutions???

Answer (score 0):

You might use a `for` loop and check if the index from `$words` exists in `$skus`:

```
$skus = [

    "Hello",
    "world",
    "sky",
    "is",
    "blue",
];

$words = array(0,2,4);
$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++) {
    if (isset($skus[$words[$i]])) {
        $result[$i] = $skus[$words[$i]];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => sky
    [2] => blue
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/c52RA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_intersect_key()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) with [`array_flip()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php):

```
<?
$skus[0] = "hello";
$skus[1] = "world";
$skus[2] = "sky";
$skus[3] = "is";
$skus[4] = "blue";

$words = array(0,2,4);

$result = array_intersect_key($skus, array_flip($words)); 
$setOrder = array_values($result); // to re order
echo "<pre>";
print_r($setOrder);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => sky
    [2] => blue
)
```

You can also use [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reset the key order.

**[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c7ac922138ecad9f91f6f789f66e536da61fac7d)**